# Filter a JSON out of a string for further processing using php

Tags: php, json, regex

In my application I make a call to an API which returns a JSON, unfortunately, this JSON is surrounded by a string with HTML elements

Example return

```
{"code":[{"name":"code","text":null,"attributes":[],"children":[]}],"message":[{"name":"message","text":"An error occurred while processing this request.","attributes":[],"children":[]}],"innererror":[{"name":"innererror","text":null,"attributes":[],"children":{"message":[{"name":"message","text":"Entiteit: Validatiefout","attributes":[],"children":[]}],"type":[{"name":"type","text":"System.Exception","attributes":[],"children":[]}],"stacktrace":[{"name":"stacktrace","text":"at Exact.Services.REST.DataServiceUpdateProvider.ErrorException(FaultException`1 fe, IExactRestConnection connection)\r\n   at Exact.Services.REST.DataServiceUpdateProvider._Closure$__6._Closure$__7._Lambda$__6()\r\n   at Exact.Services.REST.DataServiceUpdateProvider.SaveChanges()\r\n   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleNonBatchRequest(RequestDescription description)\r\n   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()","attributes":[],"children":[]}],"internalexception":[{"name":"internalexception","text":null,"attributes":[],"children":{"message":[{"name":"message","text":"Property: Ongeldige referentie, Message: Artikelcode: 'EY05547'","attributes":[],"children":[]}],"type":[{"name":"type","text":"System.Exception","attributes":[],"children":[]}],"stacktrace":[{"name":"stacktrace","text":null,"attributes":[],"children":[]}]}}]}}]}<div class="debugmsgs"><div class="debugtitle"><span id="debugtitlename">Debugger</span> | <a id="debugtitlename2">Autofill</a> <div class="debugtitle-link"><a id="debugtitle-a" href="#" onclick="toggleDebug(); return false;">inklappen</a></div></div><div class="debugerrors"><div class="debugerror debugerror-php">Undefined index: content<br /><em>C:\laragon\www\b-</div><div class="debugerror debugerror-php">Undefined index: content<br /><em></em><br /></div></div></div>
```

as you can see in the json the following happens:

```
:[],"children":[]}]}}]}}]}<div class="debugmsgs">
```

Html is appended to the string, which causes me to be unable to JSON decode.
Therefore I need to remove the HTML, or extract the JSON.

What I would like to do is to place the JSON from the returned string into a variable for further processing.

So far if been trying to do this with a regex: {(?:[^{}]|())*} but i canot seem to get it right.

Comment: is the json is in correct format? try using `json_decode` then get the array and parse

Comment: Thank you for your question, The JSON is appended by a few HTML tags, therefore the JSON cannot be decoded. This is actually the reason why I cannot further process the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your json is malformed because some kind of debug code is produced together with the output, the right way to solve this is to find out what caused the debug message below to come out

```
<div class="debugmsgs"><div class="debugtitle"><span id="debugtitlename">Debugger</span> | <a id="debugtitlename2">Autofill</a> <div class="debugtitle-link"><a id="debugtitle-a" href="#" onclick="toggleDebug(); return false;">inklappen</a></div></div><div class="debugerrors"><div class="debugerror debugerror-php">Undefined index: content<br /><em>C:\laragon\www\b-</div><div class="debugerror debugerror-php">Undefined index: content<br /><em></em><br /></div></div></div>
```

If you can't get rid of the output, other way you can use is PHP explode to remove the unwanted string, like this:

```
$string = explode("<div", $api_output); //break the string into array using the '<div' as breaking point
$result = json_decode($string[0]); //decoded version of the json output
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, (+1) This is indeed the problem, however, I do not have access to the code which produces this error due to this being a return from an external API.

Comment: well then it'll be tricky in the long run of running this API, if you couldn't contact the API developer in anyway to fix the issue then the only way is to use regex to remove anything after } from your output

Comment: how would I form this regex?